# ./ Permission denied running executables linux with x permission

Tags: linux, permission-denied

I have checked permission and I am the owner of the directory/files. I can't run .sh and can't run an executable which is the result of a compiler, made by another user. But for example I can execute makefiles.
Example

```
./ install.sh clean 
./: permission denied
```

install.sh calls a make OPT=opt clean, when I type that directly it works.
With the other executable I also get permission denied

Comment: Don't use a space after `./`. You're trying to execute the current directory.

Comment: @Biffen you are totally right, I feel such an idiot.